# Split pandas column by separator and merge to a column of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following dataframes. One of them have a column with comma separated values (df1: col2) which I want to split and join on a column of another dataframe (df2: col4).

```
df1

col1   col2
a      abc, df
b      ert
c      xyz, ghi

df2
col3   col4
id1    abc
id2    erg
id3    ghi
```

In the end, I would like to get this output

```
col1    col2         col3     col4
a       abc, df      id1      abc      
c       xyz, ghi     id3      ghi
```

```
df1 = (df1.assign(col2 = df1['col2'].str.split(','))
          .explode('col2')
          .merge(df1, on=['col4'], how='left')
          .groupby(['col1'], as_index=False, sort=False)
          .agg({'col1':','.join}))
```

I am getting this error:

```
KeyError: 'col4'
```

However this column exist in the dataframe. Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create helper column `col4` for exploding values, use for merge with default inner join and aggregate all columns:

```
out = (df1.assign(col4 = df1['col2'].str.split(',\s*'))
          .explode('col4')
          .merge(df2, on='col4') 
          .groupby(['col1'], as_index=False, sort=False)
          .agg(', '.join)
          )
print (out)
  col1      col2 col4 col3
0    a   abc, df  abc  id1
1    c  xyz, ghi  ghi  id3
```